# Get list of all organizations

Tags: ckan

i am modifyng the user register page, i hope to include a field to select a organization. I put a combobox and in this i like to show all organizations. I put this code :

```
{% set organizations = h.organizations_available('read')  %}
{% for organization in organizations %}
{{ organization.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But only show the organization list if the user is logged-in.

Searching i found that it is possible changing with 
    h.get_facet_items_dict('organization')
but I make a lot of changes and i can not get it to work.

Any helpful is very appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`organizations_available` returns the organizations the current user has access to based on the `permission` parameter you pass in.

But, if this is at the user registration or login stage, before the user is created or logged in this function may not work as there is not current user.  https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/a4ec78e04ab60f8027f4765fa4f8625c2adc5f02/ckan/lib/helpers.py#L1959

```
'''Return a list of organizations that the current user has the specified
permission for.
'''
```

I can't recall if a general user is set for the `current_user` before logged in. I think somewhere it sets the IP address possibly but not sure if this is at this point.

You could maybe [create your own helper](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/theming/templates.html#adding-your-own-template-helper-functions) that calls `organization_list`? I don't think you're really after the facet list of orgs.  https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/#ckan.logic.action.get.organization_list